# Some HTML5 tags not working in IE 7

Tags: html, modernizr, html5shiv

I made a website in HTML5 but there are some elements not working in IE9 and Lower versions. I installed HTML5SHIV and Modernizer it fixed some issues but still some elements like `<input type="email">` are not working.

Please suggest me some way to resolve it.

Comment: What exactly is "not working"? Selectors? Validation?

Answer (score 2):

It is handy to use [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/) to detect what features are supported by a particular browser. As for resolving - for not supported features you have whether to ignore unsupported browsers or build replacement (polyfill) by your hands or using libraries, with JavaScript.

Comment: Please suggest me some libraries by which i can get these features.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know concrete libraries - if I need some for particular cases, usually it is easy to google them. Try this, for example (first what I have found): http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/index.html